# How to pass AWS credentials from react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch, aws-credentials

I am using AWS SDK aws-sdk/client-batch in my react to start an AWS batch job. For this I want to pass my AWS credentials so that my batch job can start.

I know there are few different ways of passing the credentials to AWS, but if I were to use react what is the best way to pass the credentials?

Currently my code is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BatchClient, SubmitJobCommand, CancelJobCommand, DescribeJobsCommand } from "@aws- 
sdk/client-batch"

const App = () => {
 const [ batchClient, setBatchClient ] = useState(null);
 const [ submittedJobDetails, setSubmittedJobDetails ] = useState(null);
 const [ jobDetails, setJobDetails ] = useState(null);
 const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);
 const [ cancelSuccess, setCancelSuccess ] = useState(null);

 useEffect (() => {
    const awsConfig = {
         region: "us-east-1",
    };
const client = new BatchClient(awsConfig);
setBatchClient(client);
}, []);

const startBatchJob = async () => {
try{
   const params = {
             jobDefinition: "my-login-test",
             jobName: "my-poc",
             jobQueue: "my-jq-alpha",
         };
         if (!batchClient) {
             setError('Batch client not initialized..')
             return;
         }
         const command = new SubmitJobCommand(params);
         const data = await batchClient.send(command);
         console.log('Batch job started successfully: ', data);
         setSubmittedJobDetails(data.jobId);
         setError(null);
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('Error starting batch job: ', error);
         setError('Error starting Batch job');
         setSubmittedJobDetails(null);
     }
 };

return (
     <div>
       <h1>AWS Batch Job Submission</h1>
       <button onClick={startBatchJob}>Start Batch Job</button>
       <button onClick={cancelBatchJob}>Cancel Batch Job</button>
       {submittedJobDetails && (
         <div>
             <h2>Submitted Job Details: </h2>
             <pre>{JSON.stringify(submittedJobDetails, null, 2)}</pre>
         </div>
       )}
     </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Not an expert of react so I am not exactly sure where to set the AWS credentials here?

Any help is much appreaciated.

Comment: A React application will typically be running in an end user's browser; you probably can't trust that environment with AWS credentials at all.  Would it make more sense to have the React application trigger a back-end job, which can get credentials from an EC2 instance profile or something similar?

Comment: Where this react application is deployed?

Comment: This is deployed inside a VPC

Comment: What are you using for authentication of your front-end app?  Cognito?

Comment: I was locally testing this by passing accessKeyId and secretAccessKey to the BatchClient SDK. But I can't use this when I push the code to AWS. So I am not sure what should I use here to pass these 2 credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You want to authenticate a user that can assume a AWS IAM role to take actions on your AWS resources.

The AWS JavaScript SDK documentation has an example for using Cognito user pool to [list the objects in a private S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html) from a HTTP client (in this case a browser).

The [AWS SDK Javascript samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascript) also has an example for [using SQS](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascriptv3/example_code/sqs) which may provide you some hints for your own code.